# Webkit: Twitter Bootstrap modal dialog causes text to disappear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a link inside a div that is normally hidden, but appears when hovered over. It triggers a modal dialog when clicked. When the dialog is closed, the link disappears and doesn't reappear when hovered over. This bug only appears on Webkit browsers. I reproduced it on Safari and Chrome, but couldn't get it to show up in Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div class="help-inline">
  <a href="#test-modal" data-toggle="modal">click me</a>
</div>

<div id="test-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
    <h3>Modal</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">Body</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.help-inline {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:      20px;
    max-height:  20px;
    line-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.help-inline:hover {
    line-height: 21px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.help-inline a {
    position: relative;
}
```

You can see the bug in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/extropic_engine/D2WQB/

Versions used:

- Chrome 23.0.1271.101
- Firefox 18.0
- Safari 6.0.2
- Bootstrap 2.2.2
- jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: why do you use the `overflow`? `opacity` might be easier. see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2WQB/31/)

Comment: I want the div to scroll out to show the contents, rather than fading in and out.